# extracting element in a tuple of tuples

Tags: python

Task:

Each student record is represented as a `tuple` and it consists of a student's matriculation number and name.

Example: `('B0094358N', 'Shao Hong')`

Write a function `get_student_name` that returns the name of a student, when a student's matriculation number and the student records are passed into the function as arguments. The string `'Not found'` should be returned if the matrix number does not match any of the records in the database.

- Input: `get_student_name('B2245467C', student_records)`
- Output: `'Yang Shun'`

Please help me check my code:

```
def get_student_name(matric_num, records): 
    l = student_records

    for i in l:
        if matric_num == i[0]:
            return (i[1])
        elif matric_num != i[0]:
            continue
    if matric_num not in l:
        return ('Not found')
```

I get the error of hard-coding, but I don't know why.

Comment: what is `the error of hard coding`? post the stack trace.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `l = records` instead of `l = student_records`
since your parameter is called `records` and not `student_records` even though that is what you are passing as input

Comment: What is `student_records`? Please write more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simplified version. You don't need an else condition or the `continue` because the loop will return at the first match.

```
>>> def get_student_name(matric_num, records):
...     for i in records:
...         if i[0] == matric_num:
...             return i[1]
...     return 'Not Found'
...
>>> records = [('123','Jim'),('456','Bob'),('890','Sam')]
>>> get_student_name('999', records)
'Not Found'
>>> get_student_name('123', records)
'Jim'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how your student_records structure is. Guessing from your code, it looks like it's a list of tuples, so that's what we assume.

I think the problem is with your if condition after for loop. If you return for loop without a return, that means the matric_num doesn't exist in your student records. So you could try this instead -

```
def get_student_name(matric_num, records): 
    l = student_records

    for i in l:
        if matric_num == i[0]:
            return (i[1])
        elif matric_num != i[0]:
            continue
    return ('Not found')
```

Or, a little more pythonic -

```
def get_student_name(matric_num, records): 
    l = student_records

    student_name = [i[1] for i in l if i[0] == matric_num]     
    return student_name if len(student_name) > 0 else "Not found"
```